# Use Android Maps V2 marker clustering utility library in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I have a simple android app (using Android Studio) which creates a marker at the place where you touch the map at.
Code works fine. Now I want to use marker clustering using Google Maps marker clustering  utility library. I followed https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering

but they haven't explained how to setup using clustering utility library in Android Studio. I downloaded utility library from ~github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils and tried to import as module as explained at http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/

It imported the module in my opened project. Now I went into project structure and add the module dependency and selected utility library module. I did the change "compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'" in project's build.gradle But when I tried to compile the project I got below error:

**"Gradle 'MyMap' project refresh failed: Configuration with name 'default' not found. Gradle settings"**

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Satendra

Comment: There are lots of SO questions that cover this error message.

Comment: I have tried almost everything and its so frustrating. What I am trying to do is that I want to use marker clustering using google Maps V2 API for my android App.
I am able to load the map, create marker etc but not marker clustering. Can you please point to some links?
I followed:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering?hl=pl
http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/

Comment: add myapp.build dependencies { compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4'
} clean and build

Answer (score 0):

For those still finding this question..

You have to import the Maps Utilities library. Do this by adding the following code into your app Gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
}
```

Android documentation on how to set up the library: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/setup